# Fibonacci Sequence with unknown input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, fibonacci

The sequence works well. But I don't want a zero in my output. e.g 112 not 0112
This is myy code:

```
n = int(input("Enter int > than 0:"))
first_var, second_var = 0, 1
current_count = 1
if n <= 0:
    print("Error! positive integers allowed only")
else:
    while current_count <= n:
        print(first_var)
        nth_term = first_var + second_var
        first_var = second_var
        second_var = nth_term
        current_count += 1
```

Comment: assign 1 to `first_var`

Comment: Based on the source - it should start with 0, 1 https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `first_var` to also equal 1, as suggested by  user @sahasrara62.
Normally, when using the Fibonacci Sequence, you start with 1; 1, not 0; 1.

Your code should look like this:

```py
n = int(input("Enter int > than 0:"))
first_var, second_var = 1, 1
current_count = 1
if n <= 0:
    print("Error! positive integers allowed only")
else:
    while current_count <= n:
        print(first_var)
        nth_term = first_var + second_var
        first_var = second_var
        second_var = nth_term
        current_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start the sequence with 1,1 instead of 0,1 (i.e. `first_var` set to 0 and `second_var` set to 1)

Answer (score -1):

As stated by sahasrara62. You can assign 1 to first_var to achieve the output you required. But, this sequence will no more be Fibonacci sequence as Fibonacci sequence starts from 0 always.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence truly never starts or ends; it approaches the golden ratio. It technically starts infinitely into the negatives, but their code disallows anything greater than or equal to 0.